# Talend - Output data to Snowflake table with spaces in Field Names

Tags: talend

I have a very specific requirement to output data to a Snowflake table but the field names must have spaces in them.  Snowflake appears to handle this okay, but I'm unsure how Talend will as I understand Java doesn't allow it.  Can anyone help?

Also are there other tools that won't handle spaces in field names (i.e. R or Python) so we would be restricting use of the warehouse if we did that?

Comment: Hi - why do you think that Talend (or any other tool you might be interested in using) can't handle spaces in field names? Have you tried it and, if so, what issues did you find?

Comment: We attempted to do it and failed and when we googled it the responses suggested it was because Java doesn’t allow spaces in field names.  

Had also read that R doesn’t like spaces in field names:  A basic rule of R is to avoid naming data-frame columns using names that contain spaces. R will accept a name containing spaces, but the spaces then make it impossible to reference the object in a function

Comment: OK - so please can you update your question with the DDL for an example of a target table that has spaces in a column name, the error messages/logs you got from Talend when you tried to load this table and any other information that you think might be relevant to allow someone to help you resolve this issue?